# How to avoid Toggle view recursive onChange call SwiftUI

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, toggle, onchange

```
HStack{
  ForEach($rs.newsCategoryCollection){ $category in 
    Toggle(category.id, isOn: $category.isSelected)
      .toggleStyle(.button)
      .onChange(of: category.isSelected) {value in
          print("Changed")
          if value{
              rs.unselectOtherCategory(id: category.id)
              print("Selected: \(category.id)")
              viewModel.loadNews()
          }else{
              category.isSelected = true
              print("Deselected: \(category.id)")
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Here I am trying to have toggle button in horizontal view. I Want this to be used as selectors to select only one category at a time.

So after user selects any one of the category the other category should be deselected using this method: `rs.unselectOtherCategory(id: category.id)`

So I am using onChange to detect user selecting a category by tracking the change of value. But using the previous method to deselect all other categories changes the value of a previously selected category and called the onChange again.

The problem gets more complecated when I use the else block to make sure If the user tap on a selected button and deselect which makes all the button deselected, the else block can counter it and select the only button selected.

How can I avoid this repeated call of onChange.

I want to the user to be able to tap on a button and select it, other buttons will be deselected. But If an user taps on a button that is already selected the button will be remain selected.

Comment: Sounds like you shouldn’t use a `Toggle` here. Make your own picker/radio button view. Or use `Picker` with picker style `.segmented`.

Comment: If you reorganise your source of truth you can remove the need for `onChange` completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a `Picker` than a group of `Toggle`s. Don't use `Toggle`s when you want one thing to be selected at a time.

You can change the `Toggle`s to `Button`s:

```
HStack{
    ForEach($rs.newsCategoryCollection){ $category in
        Button(category.id) {
            if !category.isSelected {
                category.isSelected = true
                rs.unselectOtherCategory(id: category.id)
                viewModel.loadNews()
            }
        }
        .padding(8)
        .background(.accent.opacity(category.isSelected ? 0.1 : 0), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}
```

---

That said, I would suggest using `Picker`, with `.segmented` picker style, which looks similar to a row of buttons.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rs = ...

    @State var selectedCategory: NewsCategory.ID = "" // assuming NewsCategory.ID is a String

    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: $selectedCategory) {
            ForEach(rs.newsCategoryCollection){ category in
                Text(category.id)
            }
        } label: {
            
        }
        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        .onChange(of: selectedCategory) {
            viewModel.loadNews()
        }
    }
}
```

Now you don't even need an `isSelected` property in `NewsCategory`. If you really need it for some reason, you can add a `selectCategory` method to `rs`, e.g.

```
// selectCategory could be implemented as:
mutating func selectCategory(id: String) {
    for i in newsCategoryCollection.indices {
        if newsCategoryCollection[i].id != id {
            newsCategoryCollection[i].isSelected = false
        } else {
            newsCategoryCollection[i].isSelected = true
        }
    }
}
```

Then call this in `onChange`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I am looking for an UI where there will be options in horizontal alignment one by one seperated by each one, like top of the youtube app where you select All, Music or some thing else.

Comment: @Mahin see the edit. Perhaps you should change the `Toggle`s to `Button`s.

Comment: wonderful! I missed a very simple solution. Thanks a lot!